# Xamarin.Forms cannot reference Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, reference, using

I have a simple Xamarin project

+-MyProject 
|
+-MyProject.Android
|
+-MyProject.iOS

What I want is to be able to reference MyProject.Android in MyProject (Xamarin.Forms environment). I've seen in some other example project that you can use `using MyProject.Android;` but when I try that in my project it says

> The type or namespace name 'Android' does not exist in the namespace 'MyProject' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Your iOS and Android projects should have references to the core Forms project.  The Forms project should NOT have a reference to the platform project - it would create a circular reference AND work break the cross platform capability of Forms.

Comment: @Jason I know that it would create circular reference, but I've seen also in official example documentation that they do that (like here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-views/code). I need to use that because I need to refer to the Android MainActivity.Instance to initialize a custom Button that extend Android Button

Comment: that approach uses a Shared Project, which is deprecated now that .NET Standard is available.

Comment: @Jason oh ok got it. So is there any other way to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what it is you're trying to do.  But it sounds like a Custom Renderer is probably the answer

Comment: @Jason What I need is just to be able to refer to the Android MainActivity Instance (because to initialize the Android Button I need the Android Context in the constructor). I ave already taken a look to Custom Renderer but it doesn't seem to be helpful to my problem

Comment: again, you are not explaining what it is you are trying to accomplish

Comment: @Jason Basically in Xamarin.Forms I created a custom class CustomButton that extend Android.Widget.Button, and I had to override the constructor, that take the Android Context as parameter `public CustomButton (Android.Content.Context context) : base (context)`. So, to create an instance of that CustomButton, I need the Android Context, that I can access only through Android MainActivity `CustomButton myButton = new CustomButton(MainActivity.Instance)`

Comment: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin

Comment: @Jason thats it thank you!